# Перестройка pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть датафрейм типа:

```
name1|name2|contact|
-------------------
  a  |  b  |  3   |
  a  |  c  |  4   |
  a  |  d  |  3   |
  b  |  d  |  1   |
  b  |  c  |  2   |
  c  |  d  |  5   |
```

Можно заметить, что все элементы имеют какой-то контакт друг с другом, однако они не повторяются,  т.е. существует, например, строчка **a  |  b  |  3   |** и нет строки **b  |  a  |  3   |**. Подскажите, как можно ее сделать? Может, есть какой-то элегантный способ в стиле pandas?

Выход должен быть таким:

```
name1|name2|contact|
-------------------
  a  |  b  |  3   |
  a  |  c  |  4   |
  a  |  d  |  3   |
  b  |  a  |  3   |
  b  |  d  |  1   |
  b  |  c  |  2   |
  c  |  a  |  4   |
  c  |  b  |  2   |
  c  |  d  |  5   |
  d  |  a  |  3   |
  d  |  b  |  1   |
  d  |  c  |  5   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбираем матрицу имен (первые два столбца DF) и сортируем ее по столбцам два раза 
 - один раз в алфавитном порядке, второй раз в обратном. Создаем из отсортированной матрицы DataFrame, добавляем столбец с `contact` и объединяем два полученных DataFrame'а.

Пример:

```
names = df[['name1','name2']].to_numpy()
res = pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame(np.sort(names, axis=1), columns=df.columns[:2], 
                 index=df.index)
      .assign(contact=df["contact"]),
    pd.DataFrame(np.sort(names, axis=1)[:, ::-1], columns=df.columns[:2], 
                 index=df.index)
      .assign(contact=df["contact"])
])
```

---

результат:

```
In [72]: res
Out[72]:
  name1 name2  contact
0     a     b        3
1     a     c        4
2     a     d        3
3     b     d        1
4     b     c        2
5     c     d        5
0     b     a        3
1     c     a        4
2     d     a        3
3     d     b        1
4     c     b        2
5     d     c        5
```

Answer (score 1):

На скорую руку пока только такое решение приходит:

Исходный df:

```
  name1 name2  contact
0     a     b        3
1     a     c        4
2     a     d        3
3     b     d        1
4     b     c        2
5     c     d        5
```

решение:

```
df2=df.copy()
df2.columns=['name2', 'name1', 'contact']
res = pd.concat([df, df2]).sort_values(['name1','name2'])
```

Получаем:

```
  name1 name2  contact
0     a     b        3
1     a     c        4
2     a     d        3
0     b     a        3
4     b     c        2
3     b     d        1
1     c     a        4
4     c     b        2
5     c     d        5
2     d     a        3
3     d     b        1
5     d     c        5
```